# iPhone 6 and 6+ zoom mode on the simulator

Tags: ios, xcode

Does the iPhone simulator run apps in the "zoom" mode by default or "standard"? When I run my app in the 6+ one the graphics seem to be larger, not really sure what mode it is. I understand it is possible to force it to use the standard mode by using a launch image, is this right?

When coding an app do you need to make adjustments for the "zoom" mode. What I mean is, if the app works in standard will it just work in zoom? Just wondering if it will break my constraints or something that I setup in the interface builder. Any pointers on this would be really helpful!

Comment: do you use autolayout?

Comment: yes, have been using that

Answer (score 0):

It usually happens, when your Size Classes are disabled on the storyboard.

Comment: I actually just did an NSLog to check the screen size and it's correct for an unzoomed iPhone 6+. Looks bigger on my screen though than the one on the 5s simulator...